# select noncontinuous lines in Ed

Tags: ed

if `3,5p` prints lines 3, 4, and 5, how would one print, say, lines 4 AND 7, but not 5 and 6?

Have tried:

`3 5 p` prints line 8

`3p5p` breaks as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ed` doesn't generally let you manipulate disjoint lines like this so you'd normally just do

```
4p
this is line 4
7p
this is line 7
```

However, `ed` does allow for a command-list within the context of a `g//` command, so if you really do need all the output in one response, you can hack it with

```
1g/^/4p\
7p
this is line 4
this is line 7
```

It's ugly, it's a hack, and it's inconvenient to type. But if you really do need all the output in one pass, this will do it.